# Layering polygons and location points in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet

Oklahoma recently legalized medical marijuana, and I'm making a map of where dispensaries can set up. That depends on two things: it has to be in the right zoning area, and can't be too close to a school, church, or playground. I have two maps that show those things, but can't figure out how to layer them together. What I'm trying to achieve is showing how much of the correct zoning area is off-limits because it's too close to a school, church, etc.

The zoning code:

```
zoning_shapes <- "Primary_Zoning.shp"
zoning <- st_read(zoning_shapes)
library(dplyr)
zoning_1 <- filter(zoning, P_ZONE!="R-1")
zoning_2 <- filter(zoning_1, P_ZONE!="SPUD")
zoning_3 <- filter(zoning_2, P_ZONE!="AA")
zoning_4 <- filter(zoning_3, P_ZONE!="R-2")
zoning_5 <- filter(zoning_4, P_ZONE!="R-4")
zoning_6 <- filter(zoning_5, P_ZONE!="PUD")
zoning_7 <- filter(zoning_6, P_ZONE!="I-3")
zoning_8 <- filter(zoning_7, P_ZONE!="R-A")
zoning_9 <- filter(zoning_8, P_ZONE!="O-1")
zoning_10 <- filter(zoning_9, P_ZONE!="R-3")
zoning_11 <- filter(zoning_10, P_ZONE!="R-A2")
zoning_12 <- filter(zoning_11, P_ZONE!="R-1ZL")
zoning_13 <- filter(zoning_12, P_ZONE!="R-3M")
zoning_14 <- filter(zoning_13, P_ZONE!="R-4M")
zoning_15 <- filter(zoning_14, P_ZONE!="R-MH-1")
zoning_16 <- filter(zoning_15, P_ZONE!="R-MH-2")
zoning_17 <- filter(zoning_16, P_ZONE!="C-HC")
zoning_18 <- filter(zoning_17, P_ZONE!="HP")
zoning_19 <- filter(zoning_18, P_ZONE!="NC")
zoning_20 <- filter(zoning_19, P_ZONE!="AE-1")
zoning_21 <- filter(zoning_20, P_ZONE!="AE-2")
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
ggplot(zoning_21) + geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = 
          element_line(colour = 'transparent'))
```

The prohibited-location code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(readr)
locations <- read_csv("Marijuana_map_CSV.csv")
View(locations)
mew <- colorFactor(c("red", "blue", "purple"), domain=c("School", "Church", "Playground"))
okc_locations <- leaflet(locations) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-97.5164, 35.4676, zoom = 7) %>% 
  addCircles(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup=locations$Name, 
             weight = 3, radius=304.8, 
             color=~mew(locations$Type), stroke = T, 
             fillOpacity = 0.8) %>%
  addPolygons(data=zoning_21, fillColor = "limegreen",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, weight = 0.2,
              smoothFactor = 0.2)
okc_locations
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to add the okc_locations code to the zoning_21 code, I get one red dot that's far away and a very compressed version of the city's zoning. When I try adding the zoning polygons to the to the prohibited-points map, they don't show up.

Any ideas of how to get these two maps to play together? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah Oklahoma! Can you post a bit more about what "Marijuana_map_CSV.csv" looks like? is it just lat/long points or is it something more complicated?

Comment: Without having any reproducible data, this may be somewhat tough. Is it possible to merge the `csv` and `shapefile`? Are you trying to put the `leaflet` output into `ggplot`? And vice-versa? Are the zone shapes just polygons? A lot needs to be clarified.

Comment: Hi Stedy, thanks for getting back so fast. The CSV just has the name, address, type (church, school, or playground) and latitude/longitude. Unfortunately, I had to do it by hand, running addresses to get coordinates, so it's not so easy to reproduce. Is any of that useful?

Comment: Hi Anonymous, sorry I wasn't clear. Here's what I tried to do with merging the zoning polygons into the leaflet map: okc_zoning <- leaflet(locations) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-97.5164, 35.4676, zoom = 7) %>% 
  addCircles(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup=locations$Name, 
             weight = 3, radius=304.8, 
             color=~mew(locations$Type), stroke = T, 
             fillOpacity = 0.8) %>%
  addPolygons(data=zoning_21, fillColor = "limegreen",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, weight = 0.2,
              smoothFactor = 0.2, 
              popup=zoning_21$P_ZONE)

Comment: Hmmm, are these zoning files online? Could you add a link? My initial guess is that the projections are slightly different but it would help to take a look

Comment: @MegWingerter Do both of your data sets have the same projection? If you can convert your .csv to a .shp then that might help

Comment: Hi Stedy, I had to ask the city for the .shp, .dbf and .shx files. I'm not sure how to share them with you, though. Do you know of a way I could check on the projections?

Comment: @CAWA I'm sorry, I'm pretty new at this. Is there a way to check projections?

Comment: @MegWingerter To check the CRS of the .shp file type str(name of .shp object in R) should be near the end and look like @ proj4string....

Comment: I would recommend looking at into `lapply` or something similar for the top section of your code where you assign the zones, no need to type all of that out the long way! :)

Comment: @CAWA When I ran it with the object I'd created from reading the .shp file, I got this. It didn't work with original .shp. I don't see anything that looks like a CRS, though:    
 $ geometry  :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 20862; first list element: List of 1
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:95, 1:2] 2085163 2085068 2085044 2085043 2085042 ...
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "OBJECTID" "P_ZONE" "P_CASE" "LEGEND" ...

Comment: try scrolling down to the very bottom of the description from `str()`. Or try `sp::proj4string(your object)`

Comment: @Stedy I tried the sp::proj4string and got this error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"sf"’ I'm sorry for all this trouble.

Comment: Ahh, ok... try `sf::st_crs(your object)`

Comment: @Stedy Thank you!

Comment: @Stedy Okay, I got an NA for Coordinate Reference System. That seems like a problem. I'm sorry to keep bothering you, but do you know if there's a way to add a CRS to the data from a .shp file?

Comment: yes, I will write up a full answer

Comment: @Stedy Thank you!

Comment: @MegWingerter sorry was a busy day!
Thanks Stedy, looks like a good answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in the comments, it seems that you are having an issue with different projections, in which case you will want to use `st_transform` (documented [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf#page.72))

First, I made up some fake data:

```
locations <-
  data.frame(Name = c("St. Josephs", "St. Anthony", "Edwards Elementary"),
              type = c("Church", "Playground", "School"),
              long = c(35.4722725, 35.4751038, 35.4797194),
              lat = c(-97.5202865,-97.5239513,-97.4691759))
```

I downloaded tiger shapefiles for all counties, then narrowed to Oklahoma County:

```
us_counties <- read_sf("cb_2017_us_county_500k.shp")
ok_county <- subset(us_counties, STATEFP == "40" & NAME == "Oklahoma")

> print(st_crs(ok_county))
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4269 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs"
```

So I then used `st_transform`:

```
t2 <- st_transform(ok_county, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
> print(st_crs(t2))
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4326 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

And loading it into `leaflet` as so:

```
leaflet(locations) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-97.5164, 35.4676, zoom = 11) %>% 
  addMarkers(~lat, ~long, popup=locations$Name) %>%
  addPolygons(data=t2, fillColor = "limegreen",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, weight = 0.2,
              smoothFactor = 0.2)
```

Yields this map:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering, but I ran into an error. I put in: zoning_transformed <- st_transform(zoning_21, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") and got "Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : 
  sfc object should have crs set." I also tried to convert it from an sfc to an sf to see if that helped, but it doesn't seem to have. Is there a way to set a CRS for a file that doesn't have one, so then we can transform it? I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Try using `sp::pjroj4string()` something like `sp::proj4string(zoning_21) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"`

Comment: Got this error: "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"sf", "character"’ I also tried converting it this way: sf::st_crs(zoning_21)
zoning_sf <- st_sf(zoning_21)
print(st_crs(zoning_sf))
zoning_transf <- st_transform(zoning_sf, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") Thank you for all your help.

Comment: hmmm, ok - are the categories for `P_ZONE` just different zoning types that you want to make different colors on the final map? Maybe that can be split out into seperate polygons for each zone and then colored appropriately.

Comment: I don't mind if they all end up the same color, since dispensaries could open in any of those zones. The data just came with that categorization.

Comment: ok, I think the best way to approach this is to go step by step: first plot "Primary_Zoning.shp", then plot the points in `okc_locations`, then try to add in the `P_ZONE` categories. My guess now is the different filtering steps are what is causing the issue but experimenting by testing what works one step at a time might be the best way to resolve this.

Comment: I ran the unfiltered data and plotted it. I then tried to plot those shapes using leaflet, but they didn't show up. My code: okc_zoning <- leaflet(locations) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(-97.5164, 35.4676, zoom = 7) %>% 
  addCircles(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup=locations$Name, 
             weight = 3, radius=304.8, 
             color=~mew(locations$Type), stroke = T, 
             fillOpacity = 0.8) %>%
  addPolygons(data=zoning, fillColor = "limegreen",
              fillOpacity = 0.5, weight = 0.2,
              smoothFactor = 0.2, 
              popup=zoning_21$P_ZONE)

Comment: yeah thats pretty much what I would have done as well. I am not sure how much more I can help. If you want to email me about this, my contact info is in my profile.

Comment: Okay, thank you for sticking with me through all this.